# how to import two exported values in one import in another template in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have two exported values "environmentname" and "${environmentname}-Vpc-id" in my first template.

I want to import both the values in one command, is it possible:
something like this:

```
"Fn::ImportValue":{ "Fn::Join" : [ "-", [ {"Fn::ImportValue":"EnvironmentName"}, "Vpc-id"] ]}
```

but I am getting the error:

> Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources, imported values, or Fn::GetAZs"

EnvironmentName is the parameter in the first.template
and I have exported vpc-id and EnvironmentName.

I want to import the Vpcid from the first template.

Comment: From the error you are getting, it clearly says that you cannot nest two ImportValue function. I would go with what lexicore suggested below

Answer (score 1):

Make `EnvironmentName` a parameter in your second template as well.

If you don't do this, you'll essentially have just one environment. Then it makes no sense exporting `EnvironmentName` and using `EnvironmentName` in other export names.

Comment: i dont want to use  EnvironmentName  parameter in the other all my templates, is their any other way to do this.